# How to Set style sheet for a Phonon::SeekSlider in Qt

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qwidget, phonon, qslider

I want to know how can I set a style sheet for a **Phonon::SeekSlider** as like as a **QSlider** in Qt. With QSliders we can assign so many attributes by easily calling something like this.

```
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background:white;
border: 1px solid white;
width: 6px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

But how can I do this same with SeekSlider.I cannot set attributes by calling Phonon::SeekSlider or QSlider. Only I can do is set attributes by calling **QWidget {}** and it has no use on SeekSlider. I must be able to customize the handle,page etc...
Please anyone has ideas...Help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Phonon::SeekSlider slider control like that:

```
Phonon--SeekSlider > QSlider {

}

Phonon--SeekSlider > QSlider::handle {

}
```

etc.